how to configure Flutter web to Firebase Hosting based on flavors(environments, or build variants)?
I have been working on separating Firebase projects based on Flutter flavors for dev, staging, and prod. I have read lots of articles and set up Firebase projects for staging and prod for ios and android(only two environments for now). However, I have encountered a problem where <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY_GOOGLE_SIGNIN_CLIENT_ID" /> can not be set accordingly based on environments while integrating it to Firebase Hosting.
here is my index.html under web folder. (web/index.html)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    For more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base

    This is a placeholder for base href that will be replaced by the value of
    the `--base-href` argument provided to `flutter build`.
  -->
  <base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">

  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta content="IE=Edge" http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible">
  <meta name="description" content="A new Flutter project.">
  // whichever placed first below recognized as the targeted google signin client id
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY_GOOGLE_SIGNIN_CLIENT_ID_FOR_STAGING" />
  <meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="MY_GOOGLE_SIGNIN_CLIENT_ID_FOR_PROD" />

  <!-- iOS meta tags & icons -->
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-title" content="MY_PROJECT_NAME">
  <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="icons/Icon-192.png">

  <!-- Favicon -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png"/>

  <title>MY_PROJECT_NAME</title>
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">

  <script>
    // The value below is injected by flutter build, do not touch.
    const serviceWorkerVersion = "{{flutter_service_worker_version}}";
  </script>
  <!-- This script adds the flutter initialization JS code -->
  <script src="flutter.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="flutter_bootstrap.js" async></script>
</body>
</html>

Unlike what I have done to separate environments for android and ios, I can't find any clue to separate environments with Firebase Hosting for Flutter web anywhere(Actually I found this managing multiple index.hteml files with script file here, which I do not prefer).
I would like to achieve configuring Flutter web to Firebase Hosting based on flavors.
I will hugely appreciate it if anyone can help me with detail instructions.

You can't use flavors functionality for web application, it's only Android and  iOS feature: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/flavors
The only solution I can see in this case: prepare separate scripts to build dev/staging. Your scripts need to replace/symlink files with firebase related config stuff before build.
